# How to change additional projects with maven release plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

We create releases and upgrade the versions of our multi module project with the [maven release plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/), which is usually triggered with a [Jenkins release build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Release+Plugin). The problem is that we have a couple of modules whose versions should be updated as well, but which should **not be built** on the server - only the version upgrade should be performed. (These are just testing stuff only used occasionally by developers.) Any good ideas how to do that?

Comment: Take a look at the [versions-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the accepted policy is that every module should be built that forms part of a project. That includes those modules intended to test others.

If internally you have a situation in which a module is intended to test another but should definitely not form part of the build you may wish to extract that module into another project and adjust the module to depend on the artefacts of the older project's module.

You may still find that your CI server (such as Jenkins) recognises this dependency and builds your test project because it detects a changed dependency. In that case disable the automatic building of this test project.

You may find it less "smelly" to correct the testing procedure to ensure your test modules are designed to be run upon each build. Having a set of tests that should not be automatically run seems contrary to modern software engineering approaches.